# Force item icon refresh in Finder 10.8.2

Tags: objective-c, macos, icons, overlay, finder

Can anyone lead me to any useful link for forcing file icon refresh in new 10.8.2 version of Finder?

I'm working on this problem for last few days and I have tried almost any solution which can 
be found on internet, but those are all old samples which are compatible with old versions of Finder and do not work on newer versions of Finder (which are rebuilt on Cocoa framework).

I tried to use few commands from apple script tool to update files in Finder ('update item with necessity'), I tried few plugins from internet (nudge, finder-Refresh...), I also tried support for communication with external Mac application through ScriptingBridge framework (although very useful) but nothing gave me a desired result.

I have noticed that NSWorkspace class contains two methods: iconForFile and setIcon:forFile, 
and although I could integrate this two functions in application, iconForFile function is returning image of reduced quality, so I'm stuck in that direction also.

Any idea or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What change are you expecting in the icon?  Are you changing the file type? Or setting up a custom icon?  Or something else?

Answer (score 9):

If you need to update one Application icon, just touch the App.app folder.

Close the finder windows and issue the command:

```
touch /Applications/App.app
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, I have to run `killall Finder` and `killall Dock` also. As in one of the answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/29868969/468724

Answer (score 5):

Create a **visible** file and delete it. This will refresh finder window.

Comment: I'm new to mac os x. whats is a visible file? How to create? how to delete? I tried deleting a png file from my desktop but the delete key doesnt do anyhting. does move to trash mean delete?

Comment: You can create and delete file using NSFileManager.

Comment: Hi Parag, I wrote this ctypes code to createFileAtPath and then removeItemAtPath to a file named `ctypes make.js` on desktop. The file is created, then deleted, however my app bundle icon is not updating. If you would like yo ucan run the ctypes from firefox'es scratchpad in browser environment to replicate issue: [GitHubGIST :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-snippet-ObjC_createFileAtPath.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/be9719b3097ef5843a10) and [GitHubGIST :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-snippet-ObjC_RemoveItemAtPath.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/f9fdfe77b2b553ee9941)

Comment: Hi @Parag I made a youtube video showing that create/remove file is not updating my app bundle: [Youtube :: Demo of Create-Remove File Not Updating Icon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcAxUCWB05g) please help :( I'm using 10.9 this person here says that create-delete file should fix my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799116/finder-window-refresh-issue-yosemite?noredirect=1#comment44230859_27799116 and they are using 10.10 its so weird please help :(

Answer (score 2):

To reset for every application under Mountain Lion, try the following in Terminal:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -seed -r
```

That will kill all existing objects in launch services and reseed them recursively from the standard locations (/Applications, etc).

If you have a specific application whose data you need to override existing information, you can try:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -f <path>
```

Although I've had limited luck with the latter working in some cases, so you may end up doing the former afterwards.

Comment: I tried those two commands, but they didn't gave any result. I'm not absolutely sure what those two lines are doing, but based on your comment it seams a little bit dangerous.

Comment: I 'just' have to force refresh of file icons in Finder. It seams like a easy job, but apparently it's not...

Comment: They're not dangerous.  They are there for maintaining the databases that the used by the Finder (and other parts of the operating system) to locate which files go with which icons, etc.

Comment: Weird: the first time it worked, for a few seconds I saw the correct icon displayed... but after a while, the wrong icon came back again, and re-executing the command no longer worked.

Answer (score 2):

Type into Terminal

```
killall Finder
```

Then

```
killall Dock
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I had a `.app` i wanted to change the icon of.

Structure of my `.app`:

- `...noida.app/`

  - `...noida.app/Contents/`

    - `...`
  - `...noida.app/Contents/Resources`

    - `...noida.app/Contents/Resources/myicon.icns`
  - `...noida.app/Contents/MacOS`

    - `...`
  - `...noida.app/Contents/plist.Info`

Now I would change the icon in the resources folder. Then I made new files in all folders. It wouldn't work. The only place that i could make a new file tha twould update the icon was in the `...noida.app/` so i made new file at `...noida.app/junk folder` and then it updated.

Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I was just fighting with this on 10.10 (although it's been a problem for years now) and the only solution I found to force refreshing a bundles icon in the Finder was to:

1. Open the "Get Info Window" of the bundle you want to update and select the icon by clicking on it.
2. Paste another image as the icon (you could have copied this from another file or from any other location with this pasteboard data).
3. Press return and make sure the icon changed in the Finder.
4. Delete the icon by pressing the delete key.

After that the bundles icon was refreshed to the new .icns file in the bundles resource folder.