# Finder window refresh issue (Yosemite )

Tags: objective-c, osx-yosemite

I am working on Finder Sync extension to apply badges on files and folders ...

I want to refresh icon for particular file/folder in Finder application.
is there any way to refresh a finder window programmatically on mac OS Yosemite ???

Apart from creating and deleting a file...

Comment: Did you find solution for this? I'm having the same issue, but also for 10.9

Comment: nope...right now i am refreshing the finder window by creating a file and deleting it..

Comment: Thanks @asha im real new to macs. can you please tell me how you create and how yo udelete, is delete same thing as right click and "move to trash"?

Comment: @Noitidart yes..its exactly how it works using right click ...only difference is i m doing it programmatically

Comment: It worked but the, the solution was to to create a new file in the `.app` directory, next to the 'Contents' folder. I was trying in the Resouces, and other folders but that wasn't doing the trick.

Comment: I find an empty file "Icon?" (it should be "Icon\r") in the .app directory, it is created when I change the folder's icon, and after copy-replace the app bundle icns file, remove the "Icon?" file, it is refreshed immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I had a `.app` i wanted to change the icon of.

Structure of my `.app`:

- `...noida.app/`

  - `...noida.app/Contents/`

    - `...`
  - `...noida.app/Contents/Resources`

    - `...noida.app/Contents/Resources/myicon.icns`
  - `...noida.app/Contents/MacOS`

    - `...`
  - `...noida.app/Contents/plist.Info`

Now I would change the icon in the resources folder. Then I made new files in all folders. It wouldn't work. The only place that i could make a new file tha twould update the icon was in the `...noida.app/` so i made new file at `...noida.app/junk folder` and then it updated.

Very interesting.